Arrange $3$ red balls and $33$ white balls randomly in a circle. What is the probability that there are no more than $13$ consecutive white balls?
Arrange $3$ red balls and $33$ white balls randomly in a circle. What is the probability that there are no more than $13$ consecutive white balls?
Here is my attempt:
The $33$ white balls should be separated by the $3$ red balls into $3$ groups as follows:
$$\{13,13,7\},\{13,12,8\},\{13,11,9\},\{13,10,10\},\{12,12,9\},\{12,11,10\},\{11,11,11\}$$
Since the balls are arranged in a circle, I identify $13,12,8$ with $13,8,12,$ but I can't figure out how to calculate the total number of ways of arrangement. Is my idea correct?

I suggest:  there are $\binom {36}3$ equally likely places to put the red balls.  How many good selections are there?

@Winston: Have a look at my answer. I believe other answers have overlooked the aspect of permutations in a circle

regarding " I identify 13,12,8 with 13,8,12": this might not be correct, as one would have to mirror or flip the circle, rather than rotate it to transform between them.

@Winston: Have a look at the simpler solution that struck me.

@true blue anil:Amazing solution !

@Winston: Thanks, the idea just came from the subconscious, waking up in the morning ! $;;$ :)

Let us denote the positions in the circle with the numbers $0,\ldots,35.$
We can assume that the first red ball is fixed at position $0.$ The remaining ball with the smaller position index is at position $a$ and the ball with the largest position index is at position $b.$ There are $\binom{35}{2}$ possible arrangements for those two balls. We have to fulfill
\begin{eqnarray}
a &\leq& 14 \\
b-a & \leq & 14 \\
36 - b & \leq & 14
\end{eqnarray}
Adding the first and the second inequality gives $b\leq 28$. The last inequality is equivalent with $b\geq 22.$ Therefore, $b\in\{22,23,\ldots,28\}.$ Analogously, we get $a\in\{8,9,\ldots 14\}.$ Considering $b-a\leq 14,$ this gives us $\binom{8}{2}$ possibilities in total:
\begin{eqnarray}
b=22, && \;\;8\leq a \leq 14,\;\;\;7\;\;\mathrm{possibilities} \\
b=23, && \;\;9\leq a \leq 14,\;\;\;6\;\;\mathrm{possibilities} \\
b=24, && 10\leq a \leq 14,\;\;\;5\;\;\mathrm{possibilities} \\
b=25, && 11\leq a \leq 14,\;\;\;4\;\;\mathrm{possibilities} \\
b=26, && 12\leq a \leq 14,\;\;\;3\;\;\mathrm{possibilities} \\
b=27, && 13\leq a \leq 14,\;\;\;2\;\;\mathrm{possibilities} \\
b=28, && 14\leq a \leq 14,\;\;\;1\;\;\mathrm{possibility} \\
\end{eqnarray}
The solution is
$$
\frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{35}{2}} = \frac{28}{595} = \frac{4}{85}
$$

Could you explain why there are $\binom{8}{2}$ possibilities in total?

I believe that the circular permutation aspect has been missed. Pl. have a look at my answer.

@Winston I just used $\binom{8}{2}$ as a short form of $1+2+3+4+5+6+7.$

@trueblueanil I believe we do not agree on the elementary events. This is not necessarily a bad thing. It could indicate that the description of the problem lacks some clarification on how to conduct the experiment.

for the circular aspect: doesn't this distinguish the solutions 0,14,28, 0,14,22 and 0,8,22 ? Because those are the same arrangement - two gaps of 13, one gap of 7 with no way to distinguish them. Of course, the non-solutions with gaps of 14+ also have those duplicates..

@Chieron It depends on how the experiment is conducted and on what the "elementary events" are. If you have a circle with 36 slots and an urn with 33 white and 3 red balls in it, and you draw one after another and place them into the slots, then you get $\frac{4}{85}.$ This is my understanding of the question. If you associate all arrangements that are "rotational equivalent" with each other and treat them as one elementary event, you probably get something like true blue anil's answer.

@ReinhardMeier the experiment you just described does not fit your solution, though. Because you start with the first red ball in position 0 - you declared that the first ball to draw from the urn would be red.  And the circular nature dictates that two solutions with the same gap lengths and orderings (under circular permutation) should be considered identical.

@Chieron It fits my solution. After the experiment, I can choose a new numbering of the slots without loss of generality. The new numbering starts with 0 at one of the red balls.

hm, you might be right. The three arrangements refer to the same solution, but that solution is more likely to occur.

@Chieron Indeed.  Gaps of $8,14,14$ in any order are three times as likely to appear as gaps of $12,12,12$ (and half as likely as gaps of $7,14,15$ in any order).   If you want a counting argument, then say gaps $(8,14,14)$ and $(14,8,14)$ and $(14,14,8)$ are distinct and are each as likely as $(12,12,12)$ or $(15,7,14)$

Each possible placement of 3 red and 33 white balls on 36 places is encoded by three nonnegative integer numbers $l_1, l_2, l_3$ such that $l_1+l_2+l_3 \leq 33$. The red balls are on places with numbers $l_1+1$, $l_1+l_2+2$ and $l_1+l_2+l_3+3$. Therefore, the total number of possible placements of the balls is
$$
\Gamma = \sum\limits_{l_1,l_2,l_3 \geq 0}\Theta(33 - l_1-l_2-l_3) = 7140
$$
Here $\Theta(x) = 1$ if $x\geq 0$ and $\Theta(x) = 0$ if $x<0$, and the number $\Gamma$ was obtained on a computer. The number of placements of balls on a circle with no more than 13 consecutive white balls is equal to
$$
\Gamma_1 = \sum\limits_{l_1,l_2,l_3 \geq 0}\Theta(33 - l_1-l_2-l_3)\Theta(l_2+l_3-20)\prod_{i=1}^3\Theta(13-l_i) = 336.
$$
The second function $\Theta$ arises in the sum because the balls are arranged in a circle, and between the first and third red balls there are $33-l_2-l_3$ white balls. The number $\Gamma_1$ was also obtained on the computer. Now the desired probability is equal to
$$
p = \frac{\Gamma_1}\Gamma = \frac{4}{85} \approx 0.047
$$

Simpler solution that struck me

The first red ball can be placed anywhere, so total ways of placing the remaining red balls = $\binom{35}2 = 595$

Add $6$ more white balls,  (total $39$ white) so that each "compartment" now symmetrically can contain maximum permissible $13$ white balls between red ones

To restore to $33$ white balls, we need to take out a total of $6$ white balls from the $3$ "compartments" , which, applying stars and bars over non-negative integers, gives $= \binom{6+3-1}{3-1} = 28$ valid arrangements

Thus Pr $= \frac{28}{595} = \frac{4}{85}. \approx 4.7\%$


Original Solution
As there is some confusion about the question, I  am adding my original answer with the interpretation of the other answers.
Imagine the $3$ red balls spread out in a circle, creating $3$ "compartments" to hold the $33$ white balls subject to the constraints, with one red ball placed at an imaginary north.
We can finish what you have listed, for favorable ways
$13−12−8,13−11−9,12−11−10:6\;each\;=18$
$13−13−7,13−10−10,12−12−9:3\;each\;=9$
$11−11−11:1→28$
Note that a viable arrangement is possible only if the three reds are apart.
For total cases,
if all the reds are separate, they create three "compartments" So we can apply stars and bars over non-negative integers, thus
$x1+x2+x3=33,0≤xi,\text{ giving }\binom {35}{2}=595$ ways
Thus finally, $$Pr=\frac{28}{595}=\frac4{85}, \approx 4.7\%$$

DISCLAIMER: This answer raises the question of equivalence under rotation, but others have pointed out infirmities. Is being left, as it has attracted many commentsthat leave room for thought
Although I earlier posted an answer that agreed with the other two, I was getting a persistent feeling that something is amiss, which seems to me that the circle aspect of the problem has been ignored.

The $3$ red balls are identical, as are the $33$ white balls, so with the limit of at most $13$ balls in between red balls, note that the three red balls must be separate.

Since the white balls are only numbers, and we have seen that they must occupy three slots along a circle, if the numbers are $a,b,c$ , i.e. three different #s, circular permutations can only be $(3-1)! = 2$, and if they are of the form of $a,a,b$, e.g. $10-10-13$ there can also only be two circular permutations, viz. $10-10-13$ and $10-13-10$

Thus to finish what OP was listing, for favorable ways, we should get


$13-12-8, 13-11-9,12-11-10: 2\text{ each }= 6$
$13-13-7,13-10-10, 12-12-9: 2\text{ each }= 6$
$11-11-11: 1 \rightarrow \boxed {13}$

For total cases,

the reds around a circle create three "compartments" So we can apply  stars and bars over non-negative integers, thus

$x_1+x_2+x_3=33,\;0≤x_i\text{ giving } \binom{35}2 = 595$ ways


$$\text{ Thus finally, }P_r=\boxed{\frac{13}{595}}, \approx 2.18\%$$

First of all $(3-1)!\neq 4.$ However, this is only part of the problem. The other part is the fact that "arrange three red balls ..." might not be well-defined. What are the elementary events? In Gec's and my answer, an elementary event is choosing 3 balls out of 36 and turn them from white to red. In your answer, the elementary event is "pick one partition of 33 into 3 non-negative numbers". You identify outcomes that can be mapped to each other by rotation. I do not. I first conduct the experiment, and then choose a coordinate system with one ball having the "coordinate" 0.

@ReinhardMeier: Okay, the problem itself is confused !

"Randomly in a circle" that isn't consistent with "have 36 holes, 33 white and 3 red, shake everything up, and have everything ball land in a hole.  Repeat near infinite number of times" is going to be stretching what is usually meant by "randomly" in English.  This answer, however, does that.

This solution is an alternative to the excellent one by @RienhartMeier above - the difference is that it doesn't fix one of the balls at slot $0$, so needs to take cyclic permutations into account.
The OP's problem is equivalent to the following: you have a roulette wheel with 36 slots, and 3 (red) balls. Spin the wheel, drop the balls, and wait till they settle down, with the balls falling in one slot each. (You then have 33 empty slots, which you can fill with white balls if you like.)
There are ${36\choose 3} = 7140$ possible outcomes.  (The slots are numbered 1...36 say.)
Now consider the 'interesting' outcomes (those listed as partitions of 33 by the OP). The partition corresponds to a certain number of actual outcomes, as the partition only determines the outcome modulo rotations.
The question is how many actual outcomes are there for each partition?
If the partition is of the form

{a,b,c} (all distinct) then there are 2 x 36 = 72 outcomes (the 2 coming from the difference between the cylic ordering a,b,c and a,c,b - the 36 coming from all rotations of the wheel relative to the balls);
{a,a,b} (a≠b) then there are 1 x 36 = 36 outcomes;
{a,a,a} there are (1/3) x 36 = 12 outcomes.

This gives a total of (3 x 72) + (6 x 36) + 12 = 336
The probability is therefore
$$\mathbb{P} = \frac{336}{7140} = \frac{4}{85}\approx 0.047$$
as others have pointed out before.
